# React - Loads the last visited pages data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

When browsing around our page I noticed a strange behavior. The first request to `/recipe/1` works fine, when I go then to `/recipe/2` I still receive the data from `/recipe/1`. Clicking then to `/recipe/3` I get the data from `recipe 2`.

It seems like the page renders faster than it takes the fetch action to collect new data, but then it does not re-render with the new data.

What is the proper way to avoid that problem?

We are using react + redux + react-router.

Comment: can you provide code, or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a solution. In the constructor I save the current objects, then I fetch the new objects and check in the render function if they changed, until then I don't render the page properly.